# Azure WebJobs - how to keep the state?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a need to implement some kind of orchestrator by a WebJob. So it needs to keep a state for some kind of internal queue.
Is there any way apart from static field and from using database to keep that state?

In general the idea is simple: I have a calculation job. It get's e.g. ProductId and is doing calculations for it. It takes some time, so when another message for same ProductId is coming I need to wait, until previous calculations will finish. But at the same time I can pick a message for another ProductId if there are no running calculations for that.
I haven't found any way to make sequential processing of messages based on a specific conditions. So end up with idea to implement a stateful orchestrator which will do the trick.
Am I doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: what's kind of this webjob?it's a console project or some triggered job like queue trigger etc.?